# Why am I getting a React hook and void return type error when I call a sub-function inside useInterval

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

In Javascript, I understand you can define sub-functional components to be used in a functional component inside of other function calls.
In the following code,
I'm defining a functional component called GetProjectScans on line 5 with array and boolean parameters. Then, I'm calling GetProjectScans on line 9 in useInterval with the variables declared on lines 4 (projectScans is an IProjectScan[] object and isProjectScansFetchComplete is a boolean):

```
1 const ExecutionsPage: React.FC = () => {
2    let user:string|null = sessionStorage.getItem('user')
3    const UPDATE_TABLE_TIMER: number = 30000; // Time (ms) until we call the API again to update the scans table
4    let [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete] = useFetchProjectScansByUser(user)
5    const GetProjectScans = (projectScans: IProjectScan[], isProjectScansFetchComplete: boolean) => {
6        [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete] = useFetchProjectScansByUser(user);
7    };
8    // @ts-ignore
9    useInterval(GetProjectScans(projectScans,isProjectScansFetchComplete), UPDATE_TABLE_TIMER)
```

Heres the definition of the useFetchProjectScansByUser() on line 4. Notice its return type:

```
export const useFetchProjectScansByUser = (user: string|null): [IProjectScan[], boolean] => {
    const [projectScans, setProjectScans] = useState<IProjectScan[]>([]);
    //update here
    const [isProjectScansFetchComplete, setIsProjectScansFetchComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const {enqueueSnackbar, } = useSnackbar();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
    return [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete];
}
```

Why am I getting "TypeError: savedCallback.current is not a function" from this code? I understand this isn't an MRE, but I don't feel the need to make it one because I think my issue has to do with one of the following:

1. do i need to somehow declare the variable types of projectScans and isProjectScansFetchComplete on line 4
2. why does it say these variables aren't used inside GetProjectScans
3. why is it making me use @ts-ignore before the useInterval call on line 9

Comment: There's a few things going on here.. but you're probably getting that error because you're passing a non function to `useInterval`, which would typically accept a function. Next up, you're using local variable state as if setting it will propagate out when overridden, but it won't. This feels like a problem to be solved inside useFetchProjectScansByUser.. a fetcher hook would probably have state of its own that prevents itself from doing a second query. But one thing at a time..

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita By "Next up, you're using local variable state as if setting it will propagate out when overridden, but it won't.", what specifically are you referring to?

Comment: I suspected you were using `let` to declare `projectScans`, then overriding that variable inside your inner function with `[projectScans,...] = ` in the hopes that React would pick up that update, but it will not, because React only renders on state changes. You can't just `let` a state variable `stateX`, and reassign it `stateX = 'something else'` and hope React can pick that change up. You must use the corresponding `setX` function.

Comment: 2: It says variables aren't used in GetProjectScans, because they aren't. You have one line of code on line 6 `useFetchProjectScansByUser(user);` which clearly only uses the `user` variable.  You're also reassigning the function argument variables to the output of `useFetchProjectScansByUser`. Therefore you're not using the function arguments at all. `function fn(a) { a = 1; }` -- is `a` being used?